# Show that if $\zeta =e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)=\{q_0+q_1 \zeta + \dots + q_{n-1}\zeta^{n-1}: q_i \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, extension-field

Show that if $\zeta =e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)=\{q_0+q_1 \zeta + \dots + q_{n-1}\zeta^{n-1}: q_i \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

**My question**: The most frustrating part is to show $\frac{1}{q_0+q_1 \zeta + \dots + q_{n-1}\zeta^{n-1}}$ also has the form $q_0+q_1 \zeta + \dots + q_{n-1}\zeta^{n-1}$, which I struggle to show. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\zeta$ is an algebraic number.

Comment: @psl2Z thank you!

Comment: Related $\;-\;$ [specific example of a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486687/specific-example-of-a-field).